# Maven transitive dependency has scope compile while when dependency has provided scope

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, dependency-management

In my project I have `openejb-core` dependency with scope `provided`. However it has transitive dependency of `slf4j` and its scope is `compile` (see screenshot). All other transitive dependencies are provided as expected.

**Question**: Is it bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: is the same dependency also transitively introduced by another dependency in scope compile?

Comment: No. Just in this one

Comment: Well, its provided scope for your project. But openejb-core could have declared it with compile scope and that is the reason you could be seeing it as compile

Comment: [dependency mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) would put transitive dependencies on scope provide automatically, regardless of their declared scope. @BalajiKatika what you are saying is not correct

Comment: @EvgenyMakarov if you run `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.slf4j` do you spot it somewhere else? is there a parent pom or a `dependenciesManagement` section?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a sample pom I added:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then running:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.slf4j
```

The output is:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test-junit ---  
[INFO] com.sample:test-sample:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   
[INFO] \- org.apache.openejb:openejb-core:jar:4.7.0:provided   
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.7:provided   
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:provided
```

So as you can see Maven is coherent with its [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). The issue from your screenshot is probably on your IDE.

The table is the key point on this topic:
[image]

From it, we can see that what is transitively in scope `compile` or `runtime` goes in scope provided, what is in scope `provided` or `test` is ignored.

However, if I change my sample pom to:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And re-run the dependency tree command, the output is as following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test-junit ---
[INFO] com.sample:test-sample:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   
[INFO] +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-core:jar:4.7.0:provided  
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.7:provided  
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
```

Look now: it comes not as a child of the provided dependency, but at the same level.

Let's keep on.

If on my sample pom I remove the `sl4f-api` dependency but I add to the pom the following:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And re-re-run the dependency tree command, I finally get the same as your screenshot:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test-junit ---
[INFO] com.sample:test-sample:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   
[INFO] \- org.apache.openejb:openejb-core:jar:4.7.0:provided   
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.7:provided  
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
```

**Bingo**: the `dependencyManagement` section is overriding the scope of the transitive dependency, affecting also the mediation on `provided` scope. This is not a bug, it's by design as in this section you define kind of governance concerning your dependencies. The diagram in this case is also correct and not misleading, since the dependency is only introduced by `openejb-core` which is then affected by the `dependencyManagement` decision to put `sl4f-api` in scope `compile`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It's seems to be the case of dependencyManagement. I wasn't aware of such maven behaviour

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, cleared a few things for me.

Comment: we can see similar issue whithout any `dependencyManagement` but when a transitive dependency is brought by a provided-scoped branch **and** by another compile-scoped branch : compile scope wins for transitive dependency, which is very confusing

Comment: I found `dependency:analyze` quite handy to understand which dependency was used and which wasn't

Comment: This answer is underrated. +1